# Azure Data Factory extract JSON column from CSV

Tags: arrays, json, csv, azure-data-factory

I am using ADF to process a csv file which has in one of its columns an array of JSON Documents with same key:value pairs e.g.

Col1| Col2| Col3| Col4

Str1| Str2| Str3| [{"key1":"value1","key2":"value1"},{"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}]

As you can see, the documents have the same structure and each array could have many documents in it.

I've tried to use the flatten and parse activities but without success. The flatten activity doesn't see it as an array to flatten and having difficulty having the parse give me anything at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your source projection, what is the data type for the column? If it is not an array, try clicking on "Detect data type". Then the Flatten transformation should work.

Comment: It is detected as a string, If manually set to complex data type, it fails to throws a: 
Error:
com.microsoft.dataflow.broker.InvalidOperationException: DSL compilation failed: DF-DSL-001 - DSL stream has parsing errors
Line 27 Position 13: mismatched input ')' expecting {'parameters', 'functions', 'stores', 'as', 'input', 'output', 'constant', 'expression', 'integer', 'short', 'long', 'double', 'float', 'decimal', 'boolean', 'timestamp', 'date', 'byte', 'binary', 'integral', 'number', 'fractional', 'any', IDENTIFIER, ANY_IDENTIFIER} - RunId: 7505a6d8-7678-406e-9d41-bc72ea1b47d6

Comment: Leave it as a string and then use the Parse transformation to turn it into an array